# How to read piped data in Perl?

Tags: python, perl, pipe

I have a piece of `python` script, which I like to develop as a `perl` script.
It use `os.popen().readlines()` to get information from the pipe. I don't understand how this works in `Perl`.

Can you help me, please?

**Old Python Code:**

```
hosts = os.popen('echo "GET hostgroups\nColumns: members\nFilter: name = HG_switches" | socat - /opt/colan/nagios/var/rw/live').readlines()
for item in hosts:
print item;
```

**My Perl Code:**

```
open (my $fh, "<", 'echo "GET hostgroups\nColumns: members\nFilter: name = HG_switches" | socat - /opt/colan/nagios/var/rw/live'while (<$fh>) {  or die $!;
while (<$fh>) { 
print $fh;
}
```

Comment: What is the Problem with your perl code?

Comment: You don't close your open function... or whatever this is supposed to be `while (<$fh>) {  or die $!;`

Comment: Googling for `perl` `open` `pipes` would have led you to [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).

Answer (score 3):

Your mode to [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) isn't going to work. In order to `open` a pipe like that, you need to use a different symbol. `<` means 'open a file for reading', and you aren't.

You want;

```
open ( my $input_fh, '-|', $command_to_run ) or die $!;
```

But for something more extensive, you might want to look at [`IPC::Open2`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open2.html) and `IPC::Run2` which allows you to open input and output filehandles.

```
open2 ( my $socat_stdou, my $socat_stdin, 'socat - /opt/colan/nagios/var/rw/live' );
print {$socat_stdin} "GET hostgroups\nColumns: members\nFilter: name = HG_switches";   
print <$socat_stdout>;
```

`IPC::Run3`/`IPC::Open3` give you `STDERR` as well. And you may find, you don't actually need to shell out to `socat` but can implement that natively.

Comment: Are you sure you can't just use `<` ? I've done it before although tbh I'm not exactly clear on what OP is trying to do...

Comment: It looks like an exec pipe. A `<` won't do that.

Comment: Well, this looks good. I receive a GLOB(0x2054cb8) variable. How do I use this now?

Comment: That's a filehandle. You need to read/write from it, like you would a filehandle.

Comment: That `open2` example is BAD! It can deadlock. `open2` is too low-level for this. IPC::Run3 (or IPC::Run) should be used for this. (Not [IPC::Run2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Run2), because it doesn't exist.)